# rails update modal fields via ajax on modal index page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, modal-dialog

I am trying update modal fields on modal index page. Modal index page has two dropdown fields for each ticket. Upon change this dropdown's value should change the modal field.

[image]

There is something wrong with ajax call.apart from ajax call , everything else is working.

This is i have so far

on tickets_controller.rb

```
def edit
end
def update
 respond_to do |format|
  if @ticket.update(update_ticket_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @ticket, notice: 'Ticket was successfully 
    updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @ticket }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @ticket.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity 
     }
  end
end


private
def update_ticket_params
  params.require(:ticket).permit(:status,:priority)
end
```

js code

```
$(document).on('change',".index-ticket-status", function(){
var ticketid = $(this).attr("ticketid");
var value    = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/tickets/' + ticketid + '',
        data: {status:value },
        success: function(){
            $(this).hide;
        }
  });
```

});

Controller edit view

```
<%= form_with(model: ticket ,remote: true)  do |form| %><%= form.select(  :status, ['open', 'pending','resolved','closed','waiting for customer'], {},{:class=>"form-control status-select"}) %><%= form.submit class:'btn btn-block go' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I fixed it by adding form for each ticket on index page.

```
<%= form_for ticket, remote: true,:html => { :id => "form_#{ticket.id}" } do |f| %><%= f.select(  :status, ['open', 'pending','resolved','closed','waiting for customer'], {},{:class => 'index-ticket-status',:id =>"#{ticket.id}-index-status",:ticketid =>"#{ticket.id}"}) %><%= f.submit :style => "display: none;" %><% end %>
```

js code which submits form upon field change (submit button is hidden)

```
$(document).on('change',".index-ticket-status", function(){
 var ticketid = $(this).attr("ticketid");
 $('#form_' + ticketid).submit();
});
```

controller

```
  def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @ticket.update(update_ticket_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @ticket, notice: 'Ticket was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @ticket }
    format.js 
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @ticket.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }

  end
end
end
```